# Audio doesn't work Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, audio, alsa

The audio in my pc does not work, either with hearphones. I have tried to run
`alsactl init` from root and reboot, but nothing happened

```
uname -r :

4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
```

`lspci | grep -i audio`:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
```

`cat /proc/asound/cards`:

```
  0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                       HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7120000 irq 139
```

Comment: `pavucontrol`, `alsamixer`?

Comment: checked alsamixer, volume controls are not muted

Comment: show ` cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 | grep -i codec`

Comment: I'm not sure if it would matter, but did you install each of `alsa-base`, `alsa-oss`, `alsa-utils`?

Comment: I miss only alsa-oss, installed it but nothing changed. If need I upload the alsa-info txt generated -----> http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=36800938676843054408

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on my cluster (now Debian Jessie with kernel release 3.16.0-4-amd64) after the upgrade from Debian Wheezy. In my case I noticed that if I remove and then reloading manually the kernel module everything works fine. For this behavior a (not very nice) solution could be add in your file `/etc/rc.local` the following commands:

```
rmmod <modulename>
modprobe <modulename>
```

However, another (better) solution, which I strongly recommend you, is upgrade the kernel. For example you can easily install a new kernel from `jessie-backports`.

Comment: I've updated to the last 4.7.0-0.bpo.1 kernel image but nothing changed. 
What do you mean with <modulename>?

Comment: The name of the kernel module used by your audio device. You can find it with `lspci -s 00:1f.3 -v | grep -i kernel`. Note that I took `00:1f.3` from your question. If there is no module loaded then this is the reason why it does not work the audio.

Comment: I found 
 Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
 Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

Added 
rmmod snd_hda_intel
modprove snd_hda_intel
in /etc/rclocal (before the exit 0)

Anyway nothing appear to change

Comment: Before adding these commands in`rc.local` try to run them in a root shell and see if this solution works for you too. `rc.local` is just a way to execute these commands on startup because it's annoying write them everytime.

Comment: At runtime doesn't work the first command: rmmod: ERROR: Module snd_hda_intel is in use

Comment: If your Problem still exists marte3707, wie can try to solve it in chat <http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48542/audio-doesnt-work-debian-jessie